# JQ: Merge several json arrays on index key

Tags: json, merge, key, jq

I actually looking for an solution to merge several (3-4) arrays based on several "index" keys.

Example Array 1:

```
{"Fan":[{ "Last Name":Mueller,"Firstname":Martin,"Adress":Madisson Square,"City":"New York","DegreesIndex":3,"SchoolIndex2":1,}]
```

DegreesIndex and Schoolindex refers to two different Keys in two other Arrays:

example Array 2:

```
{"Degrees":[
{"DegreesIndex":3,
"Key":"12759303,
"Degrees":1.6}]}
```

example Array 3:

{"School":[
{"SchoolIndex":1,
"Teaser":"12759303.8,
"Trainer":Miller}]}

How can i merge that arrays based on the "index" keys with JQ 1.5 under windows10?

Regards
Timo

Comment: 1. Please fix the JSON. 2. Please clarify the question after reviewing the guidelines at http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1):

I believe this may be close to what you're looking for:

```
# input: an object
def merge_by_index(obj; ix):
  ix as $index
  | . + (obj | map( select( ix == $index)) [0] )
  | del(ix) ;
```

After cleaning up your sample input, and assuming a1, a2, and a3 are the
three top-level objects:

```
a1
| .Fan[0] |= merge_by_index(a2|.Degrees; .DegreesIndex)
| .Fan[0] |= merge_by_index(a3|.School; .SchoolIndex)
```

produces:

```
{
  "Fan": [
    {
      "Last Name": "Mueller",
      "Firstname": "Martin",
      "Adress": "Madisson Square",
      "City": "New York",
      "Key": 12759303,
      "Degrees": 1.6,
      "Teaser": 12759303.8,
      "Trainer": "Miller"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would approach this.  This is a little more verbose then [peak](https://stackoverflow.com/users/997358/peak)'s approach.

First define some arrays with the data.  Note that I took the liberty of adding another entry for testing what happens when there isn't a matching **DegreesIndex** or **SchoolIndex** for the given **Fan**.  I like using functions here because you can easily replace these with whatever logic you need to get your real data.

```
def array1: {
  "Fan": [
    {
      "Last Name":"Mueller", "First Name":"Martin",
      "Address": "Madisson Square", "City": "New York",
      "DegreesIndex": 3, "SchoolIndex": 1
    },
    {
      "Last Name":"Roberts", "First Name":"Bob",
      "DegreesIndex": 2, "SchoolIndex": 4
    },
    {
      "Last Name":"Skywalker", "First Name":"Luke",
      "DegreesIndex": 5, "SchoolIndex": 1
    }
  ]};

def array2: {
 "Degrees": [
     { "DegreesIndex":3, "Key": "12759303", "Degrees":1.6 },
     { "DegreesIndex":2, "Key": "2",        "Degrees":2 }
  ]};

def array3: {
  "School": [
    { "SchoolIndex":1, "Teaser":"12759303.8", "Trainer":"Miller" },
    { "SchoolIndex":2, "Teaser":"2",          "Trainer":"Miller" }
  ]};
```

Now define a few simple lookup functions which will return the record matching the specified key.  Note the use of the [ ... ][0] construct to return a null if the item isn't found instead of causing the **Fan** to be ommitted entirely.

```
def LookupDegrees($i):
  [
      array2
    | .Degrees[]
    | select(.DegreesIndex == $i)
  ][0]
;

def LookupSchool($i):
  [
      array3
    | .School[]
    | select(.SchoolIndex == $i)
  ][0]
;
```

All that makes the main routine simple:

```
  array1
| .Fan[] 
| .Degrees = LookupDegrees(.DegreesIndex)
| .School = LookupSchool(.SchoolIndex)
```

Here is the result I get when I run it with jq -n -f file.jq

```
{
  "Last Name": "Mueller",
  "First Name": "Martin",
  "Address": "Madisson Square",
  "City": "New York",
  "DegreesIndex": 3,
  "SchoolIndex": 1,
  "Degrees": {
    "DegreesIndex": 3,
    "Key": "12759303",
    "Degrees": 1.6
  },
  "School": {
    "SchoolIndex": 1,
    "Teaser": "12759303.8",
    "Trainer": "Miller"
  }
}
{
  "Last Name": "Roberts",
  "First Name": "Bob",
  "DegreesIndex": 2,
  "SchoolIndex": 4,
  "Degrees": {
    "DegreesIndex": 2,
    "Key": "2",
    "Degrees": 2
  },
  "School": null
}
{
  "Last Name": "Skywalker",
  "First Name": "Luke",
  "DegreesIndex": 5,
  "SchoolIndex": 1,
  "Degrees": null,
  "School": {
    "SchoolIndex": 1,
    "Teaser": "12759303.8",
    "Trainer": "Miller"
  }
}
```

This should be easy to adjust if you need a different nesting or output.